# How to do a Multilabel classification where the label order is important?

Tags: machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I am new to machine learning and I hope I used the right term in the question. So  I am doing carbon composite modelling for my college project, and each composite sample are created by stacking carbon fiber of different angles(for this project it just include 0, 45, 90,-45, these 4 angles) and a sample can contains 8,12 or 16 of such fiber so a actual sample would be  named sth like '0_90_-45_45_90_45_-45_0' or '90_-45_-45_-45_45_-45_0_45_90_-45_-45_-45_0_-45_90_0'
and I have a bunch of data including continous numerical like energy or reaction force, and some screenshot of the composite damage.

How can I train the model so that it can  generate screenshot picture and numerical data by inputing angles? More specifcally I wish to know how to set the target variable in a proper way,my bet is set up a '1st/2nd...stack_angle' variable and restrict it to have discrete value from the 4 angles, but in that case I dont know if using this way would the model acknowdlege the order of the angels are also important(ie: "45_-45_90" behave differently to "-45_90_45" in real world experiment),also my supervisor say I should split the samples based on the number of stackes, then I have to deal with 8,12,16 stackes samples seprately

This is a big question to ask and I really underestimate the project diffculty.I am just starting about learning this topic, any bit of information is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using an Instron hardness tester or something similar,
where you apply a known force and measure the size of the resulting damaged region.
It would probably be convenient to make several measurements
of a given sample, perhaps doubling the applied force each time.
Pay attention to the ratio of damaged region size to fiber layer thickness.

Use exclusively 16-layer samples.
Ignore ±45° angles for now.
That still leaves an interesting design space to explore.

Measure a "boring" stack, with all layers aligned.

Now introduce a top layer at 90°, and make sixteen measurements
where you move that 90° layer down through the stack.
Presumably at some point its effect becomes imperceptible,
at least when applying small forces.
Play a classification game with your data:
given the hardness tester measurement,
can you tell which of the 17 different samples was used?
Which force level(s) let you win the game?
Which samples are difficult to distinguish?
Does an OLS linear model adequately capture the physics?

Now introduce another fourteen samples,
where a pair of "boring" stacks are oriented 90° apart.
So we have a 2 + 14 layer stack, another is 3 + 13, and so on.

Now start introducing thicker regions,
with a fiber orientation change at two or more layers.
Do your existing simple models still match observations?
You might need to resort to XGBoost random forest at this point.

I recommend naming each sample with the "change in angle" at each layer.
So a boring sample would be sixteen zeros, and another sample
might be {0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, ...} to indicate a pair of aligned layers
atop fourteen aligned layers.